# Customize size of a button widget in android

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

So i have this idea to create an `activity` that have only `buttons` which split the screen as presented in the picture:

[image]

I was thinking about creating some functions for each button. those functions will be dependent on the y and x axis of the screen.

Can you guys give me a direction on how to do this in a manner of using the Button and imageButton widgets in my `activity.java` file?

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is implementing your own custom view and handle all clicks that you want to fire specific events yourself.

Comment: Coustem View is The Best for This..............

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396194/creating-a-triangular-shaped-button-for-android-application).Maybe you could do a similar thing for all the ImageButtons and overlap them accordingly?